# How can I get a random number in Ruby (v2.6.3)

Tags: ruby, random, random-seed

I'm doing an assignment in which I have to make a simple card game. The tutor has provided me with a method to generate a random card - which I'm not allowed to change:

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end
```

And I have tried to make a method that adds cards to the players hand, calling the `random_card` method each time:

```
def move(random_card)
  player_hand = []
  while true do
    puts "Make a move. Enter 'hit' or 'stick' "
    choice = gets.chomp
    if choice == "stick"
      break
    elsif choice == "hit"
      # this is currently giving me the same card for each "hit"
      # but a different one each time I run the code.
      player_hand.push(random_card)
    end
  end
  # TODO change this to return
  puts player_hand
end
```

Each time I `hit' the same card gets added to the hand, 
My question is how to prevent this and for the method to return a "new" random card each time we run through the loop.

Thanks.

Comment: If you feel that none of the answers addresses the question to your satisfaction, can you clarify why with an edit?

Answer (score 3):

You've used the name `random_card` for two different things: 1) the method given you by your instructor; and 2) the name of the argument to your `move` method.

The second usage defines a local variable, which [masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking) (or shadows) the method name.  In other words, within the `move` method `random_card` refers to whatever value you passed in when you called `move`. It does ***not*** call the method.

Here's a simple illustration:

```
def foo
  %w(hi hey howdy)[rand 3]
end

def bar1
  puts foo
end

def bar2(foo)
  puts foo
end

5.times { bar1 }  # produces a random selection of hi's, hey's, and howdy's
puts
5.times { bar2 "Help!  I'm stuck!" }  # prints the passed message 5 times
puts
5.times { srand 12345; bar1 }  # produces "howdy" 5 times
```

Given what you've shown, you probably don't need an argument to `move`.  If you do, give it its own name.  Also make sure you aren't messing with `srand` somewhere else in your program.

---

Yet another alternative would be to indicate that you want to use the method rather than the argument with the same name by using parentheses.  With the example above, change `bar2` to:

```
def bar2(foo)
  puts foo()
end
```

The empty parentheses make it clear this is an invocation of the method `foo`, not a reference to the (now unused) argument `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple solution to your problem

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]

  cards[rand(13)]
end

def move(callback)
  player_hand = []
  while true do
    puts "Make a move. Enter 'hit' or 'stick' "
    choice = gets.chomp
    if choice == "stick"
      break
    elsif choice == "hit"
      player_hand.push(callback.call)
    end
  end
  puts player_hand
end
```

and you can call this method as

`move(method(:random_card))`